# How to remove the icons corresponding to “by” (author) and “date” from posts?

Tags: posts, icon

I figured out how to remove the author and date data from posts, but the corresponding icons still appear.

[image]

What file or function should I edit to remove those?

Update: I've figured out how to hide them by changing the color to match the background, but this still leaves a large gap where it went...

Comment: What are the icons you're referring to?

Comment: @TomJNowell Screenshot added

Comment: This is probably not a very good solution because it leaves the space there were the icons would go, but I found a hack which is to make them the same color as the background like this `ul.post-meta * {
    font-size: 0px;
    color: white !important;
    font-family: cursive !important;
}`

Comment: where is that screenshot taken from? Is this on the frontend? Please provide context, it is not clear where you're doing this, or what page that is, or if it's an admin screen or a frontend screen

Comment: @TomJNowell It's a post header in WordPress in the default Twenty Twenty theme. I'm trying to remove the header from posts and not leave a big blank gap in their place. It's frontend.

Comment: Ah, I wish you had mentioned this earlier. Is there a reason you can't create a child theme, copy the template and delete the PHP code that displays this?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes that’s what I need to do I just don’t know specifically what code to remove or add within the child theme. I am a Python programmer, new to WordPress PHP.

Comment: The code that displays those icons, if you're new to WP and PHP I would suggest doing this in a local environment by trial and error so you can gain familiarity. Themes do not use the same method for implementing this, so there's no generic answer that works for all themes, just as there is no single way to structure the HTML and CSS to produce this

Comment: @TomJNowell Understood thanks. This is the default theme (Twenty Twenty) so I was hoping enough people use it someone might be able to help. Seems like I’ve found just about everything else regarding this theme online. I can use the Web Dev console in my browser to see the property names within the rendered code but I am not able to link that to what I should do in WP

Comment: Have you tried looking at the HTML class, opening the theme in a code editor, then  searching the project/theme folder for that HTML class string in PHP files? I just found it by searching for the string "by " on github in https://github.com/WordPress/twentytwenty  in the `twentytwenty_get_post_meta` function. You should be able to do this in any decent code editor without needing any knowledge of PHP or WordPress. In Visual Studio Code it's `Search` under the view menu and in the main action bar, in Sublime Text it's right click `find in folder`

Comment: The code also reveals the entire thing was wrapped in an `<li>` tag with a HTML class that could be hidden via `display: none;`, e.g. `.post-date { display none; }`